# Azure Devops Download Artifacts multiple Github Artifacts (Updated with more logs)

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Release pipeline (not YAML) that has two Github Artifacts and when I run this pipeline on my self-hosted pool it fails with the message below, but when I run this on Microsoft hosted pool there are no issues. When I run the Release with a single Github artifact there are no problems, and it doesn't matter which repo I use, but as soon as I add the second it fails.

```
2020-11-17T20:38:06.2990529Z ##[error]Downloading artifacts failed: System.InvalidOperationException: NotFound
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.GitHubHttpClient.GetUserRepo(String accessToken, String repositoryName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.GitHubArtifact.GetArtifactDetails(IExecutionContext context, AgentArtifactDefinition agentArtifactDefinition)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.<ConvertToArtifactDefinition>b__1()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.ConvertToArtifactDefinition(AgentArtifactDefinition agentArtifactDefinition, IExecutionContext executionContext, IArtifactExtension extension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifacts(IExecutionContext executionContext, IList`1 agentArtifactDefinitions, String artifactsWorkingFolder)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifactsAndCommitsAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, Object data)
2020-11-17T20:38:06.3063035Z ##[error]NotFound
```

Full log output of the Download Artifact task within the Release Pipeline in the UI.

```
2020-11-19T15:09:10.4117956Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Download Artifacts'
2020-11-19T15:09:10.4163138Z ##[debug]Evaluating: SucceededNode()
2020-11-19T15:09:10.4171229Z ##[debug]Evaluating SucceededNode:
2020-11-19T15:09:10.4220768Z ##[debug]=> True
2020-11-19T15:09:10.4231140Z ##[debug]Result: True
2020-11-19T15:09:10.4283461Z ##[section]Starting: Download Artifacts
2020-11-19T15:09:10.5826383Z Creating artifacts directory: D:\a\r1\a
2020-11-19T15:09:10.6184188Z Created artifacts directory: D:\a\r1\a
2020-11-19T15:09:10.6184524Z Downloading artifact
2020-11-19T15:09:10.6210816Z Starting artifacts download...
2020-11-19T15:09:10.7991498Z Downloading linked artifact _Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module_AzDevOps of type GitHub...
2020-11-19T15:09:10.8024573Z Ensuring artifact folder D:\a\r1\a\_Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module_AzDevOps exists and is clean.
2020-11-19T15:09:10.8046840Z Received GitHub artifact Details
2020-11-19T15:09:10.8245609Z Syncing repository: 99960c9d-3ff4-4c28-91c2-71edc13c1775 (GitHub)
2020-11-19T15:09:10.8284949Z Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'git.exe'.
2020-11-19T15:09:10.8314573Z ##[debug]Path: 'C:\agents\2.177.1\externals\git\cmd;C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Mercurial\;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin;C:\ProgramData\kind;C:\vcpkg;C:\cf-cli;C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\;C:\Program Files\Mercurial\;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\stack\2.5.1\x64;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ghc.8.10.2.1\tools\ghc-8.10.2\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\mysql-5.7.21-winx64\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3\bin\x64;C:\SeleniumWebDrivers\GeckoDriver;C:\Rust\.cargo\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitHub CLI;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\pipx_bin;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\go\1.14.12\x64\bin;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.7.9\x64\Scripts;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.7.9\x64;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Ruby\2.5.8\x64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8u275-b01\bin;C:\aliyun-cli;C:\npm\prefix;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Azure Dev Spaces CLI;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Azure Dev Spaces CLI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Docker;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\pulumi\tools\Pulumi\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\bin;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;c:\tools\php;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\SeleniumWebDrivers\ChromeDriver\;C:\SeleniumWebDrivers\EdgeDriver\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\SessionManagerPlugin\bin\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps'
2020-11-19T15:09:10.8342029Z ##[debug]Get git version.
2020-11-19T15:09:10.8361614Z ##[command]git version
2020-11-19T15:09:11.0335550Z git version 2.28.0.windows.1
2020-11-19T15:09:11.0352149Z ##[debug]Detect git version: 2.28.0.
2020-11-19T15:09:11.0824656Z ##[debug]Get git-lfs version.
2020-11-19T15:09:11.0828900Z ##[command]git lfs version
2020-11-19T15:09:11.7703765Z git-lfs/2.12.1 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.14.10; git 85b28e06)
2020-11-19T15:09:11.7716536Z ##[debug]Detect git-lfs version: '2.12.1'.
2020-11-19T15:09:11.7719152Z ##[debug]Set git useragent to: git/2.28.0 (vsts-agent-git/2.177.1).
2020-11-19T15:09:11.7741726Z ##[debug]Checking if the repo on D:\a\r1\a\_Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module_AzDevOps matches the expected repository origin URL. expected Url: https://github.com/Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module/AzDevOps.git
2020-11-19T15:09:11.7743659Z ##[debug]Repository is not found since '.git' directory does not exist under. D:\a\r1\a\_Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module_AzDevOps
2020-11-19T15:09:11.7764723Z ##[debug]Init git repository at: D:\a\r1\a\_Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module_AzDevOps.
2020-11-19T15:09:11.7774786Z ##[command]git init "D:\a\r1\a\_Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module_AzDevOps"
2020-11-19T15:09:11.9383075Z Initialized empty Git repository in D:/a/r1/a/_Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module_AzDevOps/.git/
2020-11-19T15:09:11.9440442Z ##[debug]Add git remote: origin to url: https://github.com/Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module/AzDevOps.git for repository under: D:\a\r1\a\_Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module_AzDevOps.
2020-11-19T15:09:11.9441215Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://github.com/Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module/AzDevOps.git
2020-11-19T15:09:12.0277739Z ##[debug]Disable git auto garbage collection.
2020-11-19T15:09:12.0278156Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2020-11-19T15:09:12.1001688Z ##[debug]Checking git config http.https://github.com/Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module/AzDevOps.git.extraheader exist or not
2020-11-19T15:09:12.1003216Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://github.com/Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module/AzDevOps.git.extraheader
2020-11-19T15:09:12.1601235Z ##[debug]Checking git config http.proxy exist or not
2020-11-19T15:09:12.1603554Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2020-11-19T15:09:12.2256020Z ##[debug]Fetch git repository at: D:\a\r1\a\_Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module_AzDevOps remote: origin.
2020-11-19T15:09:12.2268539Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-11-19T15:09:13.0340677Z remote: Enumerating objects: 246, done.        
2020-11-19T15:09:13.0342064Z remote: Counting objects:   0% (1/246)        
2020-11-19T15:09:13.0673948Z remote: Counting objects: 100% (246/246), done.        
2020-11-19T15:09:13.0674315Z remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/167)        
2020-11-19T15:09:13.0763448Z remote: Compressing objects: 100% (167/167), done.        
2020-11-19T15:09:13.0957394Z Receiving objects:   0% (1/246)
2020-11-19T15:09:13.1124395Z Receiving objects: 100% (246/246), 117.42 KiB | 7.34 MiB/s, done.
2020-11-19T15:09:13.1129647Z Resolving deltas:   0% (0/134)
2020-11-19T15:09:13.1197683Z Resolving deltas: 100% (134/134), done.
2020-11-19T15:09:13.2704292Z From https://github.com/Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module/AzDevOps
2020-11-19T15:09:13.2707815Z  * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
2020-11-19T15:09:13.2710140Z  * [new tag]         v1.0.0     -> v1.0.0
2020-11-19T15:09:13.2712557Z  * [new tag]         v1.0.1     -> v1.0.1
2020-11-19T15:09:13.2714575Z  * [new tag]         v1.0.2     -> v1.0.2
2020-11-19T15:09:13.3141769Z ##[debug]Checkout fc1273f68bd971c8fa04fb03e116597d248044b9.
2020-11-19T15:09:13.3142871Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force fc1273f68bd971c8fa04fb03e116597d248044b9
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4037551Z Note: switching to 'fc1273f68bd971c8fa04fb03e116597d248044b9'.
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4038002Z 
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4038288Z You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4038646Z changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4039054Z state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4039262Z 
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4039518Z If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4039892Z do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4040151Z 
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4040329Z   git switch -c <new-branch-name>
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4040528Z 
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4040903Z Or undo this operation with:
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4041199Z 
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4041382Z   git switch -
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4041512Z 
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4041758Z Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4042000Z 
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4042526Z HEAD is now at fc1273f Each function has one or more oauth scopes that apply to it. There should be a file that lists those out
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4129905Z Downloaded linked artifact _Azure-Devops-PowerShell-Module_AzDevOps
2020-11-19T15:09:13.4132136Z Starting artifacts download...
2020-11-19T15:09:13.8258173Z ##[error]Downloading artifacts failed: System.InvalidOperationException: NotFound
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.GitHubHttpClient.GetUserRepo(String accessToken, String repositoryName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.GitHubArtifact.GetArtifactDetails(IExecutionContext context, AgentArtifactDefinition agentArtifactDefinition)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.<ConvertToArtifactDefinition>b__1()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.ConvertToArtifactDefinition(AgentArtifactDefinition agentArtifactDefinition, IExecutionContext executionContext, IArtifactExtension extension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifacts(IExecutionContext executionContext, IList`1 agentArtifactDefinitions, String artifactsWorkingFolder)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifactsAndCommitsAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, Object data)
2020-11-19T15:09:13.8344372Z ##[error]NotFound
2020-11-19T15:09:13.8349713Z ##[debug]System.InvalidOperationException: NotFound
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.GitHubHttpClient.GetUserRepo(String accessToken, String repositoryName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.GitHubArtifact.GetArtifactDetails(IExecutionContext context, AgentArtifactDefinition agentArtifactDefinition)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.<ConvertToArtifactDefinition>b__1()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.ConvertToArtifactDefinition(AgentArtifactDefinition agentArtifactDefinition, IExecutionContext executionContext, IArtifactExtension extension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifacts(IExecutionContext executionContext, IList`1 agentArtifactDefinitions, String artifactsWorkingFolder)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifactsAndCommitsAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, Object data)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.JobExtensionRunner.RunAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.RunStepAsync(IStep step, CancellationToken jobCancellationToken)
2020-11-19T15:09:13.8356839Z ##[section]Finishing: Download Artifacts
```

Originally I thought perhaps there was an issue with the repository itself, but this is showing up with old repo's and new ones. I've validated that all agents are running the latest ADO agent 2.175.2 (as of this post). This happens on both Windows agents and Linux agents so I'm unclear what the difference would be.

If anyone has any thoughts I'm open to suggestions or advice!

Thanks!

Comment: I tested Release Pipeline(Github Artifacts) with the Agent version 2.175.2 . But it could work fine when I add two Github Artifacts. Can you share the release artifacts settings?

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT what specifically do you need? They are private github repos in the same org.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT To be clear these are release pipelines in the UI not YAML pipelines and yesterday I ran these on my own ado org and was able to have two github artifacts and it successfully downloaded them both, but today it failed. I'll place the full output of the download artifact above in the original question.

Comment: Yes. I test the Release pipelines in the UI.  And I also add the private github repos from the same org too. But the job could always run successfully in my org.  From the comment above, do you mean that it can run successfully sometimes？ From the error log, it indeed stops downloading the second artifacts. But it doesn't show much error information. Could you please set the variable : `system.debug = true` and help us collect the detailed debug log?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I have enabled debug logging and it's not much better, but I am updating the original post above to include the debug statements, again just cut out the downloading progress

Comment: So, I tested this on my personal ado org earlier this week with two github repos and it just worked no issues. But subsequent trials have all failed, additionally this has never worked in the org that we use for my work.

Comment: According to your information, it seems that this issue relates to the organization. Could you please share the region of the organization? You could get the region information in  `Organization Settings -> Overview`.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT both orgs are in East US 2

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT any updates?

Comment: This question is really strange. I still can't reproduce it in the same region. You could try to unselect the artifacts in the  `Agent Job -> Artifact download`. Then you could add a Powershell task to manually download(Git command) the repos: e.g. `git clone xxxx`. Please check if you could download the artifacts successfully.  On the other hand, the latest agent version is `2.177.1`, please check if the latest agent could make some changes.

Comment: **Additional suggestion**: you could try to manally clean up the self-hosted agent  `D:\a\r1\a` folder  and run the release again. I guess the files that have been downloaded before may have some impact on the download of the github repos.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I'll see if I can get to that today, but for clarity on my personal org i'm the microsoft hosted agents, and the time between runs is measured in days so i feel confident that i'm not always getting the same host ;-) but i'm happy to be wrong!

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT any thoughts on my latest update?